# Multiple local temp tables with the same name

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am writing a set of stored procedures that aggregate data from large datasets.

The main of stored procedure makes a call to another server(s) where the data is located.  The data is calculated in steps and stored in multiple temp tables (currently global temp tables) and then pulled to the server I'm sitting on (this is done because of the way the linked servers are setup).

Right now I'm trying to write dynamic SQL to create temp tables with a unique identifier because multiple people may run the stored procedures at the same time. However because of the number of sub-steps to this process its getting complex so I'm wondering if I'm over thinking it.

My question is if I simplify and just use local temp tables will I run into problems because the tables will have the same name?  NOTE: Users may have same login user names.

Comment: Does each user have their own dedicated database session? Often, an application will use one session for multiple users simultaneously or pool them so a user isn't assured of using the same session while using the application.

Comment: It should be fine. Can you show an example of what you are doing?

Comment: They will be using the same log in account (these are grouped by team) which is part of the concern I have.

Comment: Currently the sproc passes parameters to a sproc in another server. That server creates a temp table using tmp+timestamp and processes those calculations then sends them back to server 1 to complete and display.

Answer (score 1):

Temp table names are per-session. When you call `SqlConnection.Open` you get a new session. Normally, applications do not share sessions between HTTP requests. Neither is this a common thing nor is this a good thing.

I don't believe you have a problem. If you get name clashes then you should fix the application to not share sessions in the first place.